# Should I use delete or delete[] in this kind of situation?

Tags: c++

I'm creating linked list with c++ and I allocated list's memory by using "new" every time.

So I have to use delete to prevent memory leak here, but I'm confused with this because I don't know whether I have to use delete or delete[].

Should I regard the linked list as an array?

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

I used the code above to make linked list and just like the code you see, I connected the nodes by using pointer.

So.. do I have to use delete, or delete[] to prevent memory leak?

Comment: hint: if you are wondering whether you can do something trivial, you can begin by trying it, and the compiler will tell you whether it was a good idea or not.  Posting a stackoverflow question for something that the compiler can tell you if you just hit the "compile" key is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: sorry. I just wanted to be sure.. not that I just wanted to finish my coding but wanted to know the detailed principle for this..

Comment: [new and delete (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: thanks for the help :)

Comment: There is an easy way to remember: If you called `new`, then call `delete` but if you called `new[]` then call `delete[]`.

Comment: thanks for the good tip :D!!

Answer (score 0):

To delete the whole list you would have to delete node by node hence using delete

Comment: Actually, I'm using for loop and delete to destroy the list's memory but it does not work.

Comment: I called node *p and tried to delete, but it does not work.
void destroy(node *p) {
 for( ; p != NULL ; p = p->next) {
  delete // for here, what should I do?
 }
}

delete p->data cannot work here?

Comment: @HaileyK use `delete p;`